# Can't install pandas for Python34 in EC2

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install pandas in an EC2 instance using the AWS linux distro for use with Python34.

I ran:

```
sudo pip install pandas
```

and I was able to successfully install pandas for the python 2.7 version but when I run:

```
sudo python34 -m pip install pandas
```

I get the error:

> gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -DDYNAMIC_ANNOTATIONS_ENABLED=1
>   -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -Ipandas/_libs/src/klib -Ipandas/_libs/src -I/usr/local/lib64/python3.4/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.4m -c pandas/_libs/index.c -o build/temp.linux-x86_64-3.4/pandas/_libs/index.o -Wno-unused-function
>       pandas/_libs/index.c:4:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
>        #include "Python.h"
>                           ^
>       compilation terminated.
>       error: command 'gcc' failed with exit status 1

followed by:

```
Command "/usr/bin/python34 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-zsa12w6w/pandas/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-svj_8okf-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-zsa12w6w/pandas/
```

How do I successfully install pandas for the python34 version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'm guessing you have an old version of pip, otherwise it would try to install via a wheel (binary dist).  So one option would be to upgrade pip, then install pandas.  (`python34 -m pip install -U pip`)
2. If you do want to build pandas from source, or any python c-extension, you need to install the python development headers, probably something like `yum install python34-python-devel.x86_64`

Comment: actually I just updated to python3.6 on the EC2 instance and it solved it.

Comment: @user2907249 Yes updating the python to 3.6 helped in my case as well. But this issue could not be fixed in virtualenvironment. Not sure why